# Should I sub-domain my VPS name servers?

Tags: cpanel, nameserver

While trying to setup up my VPS, I came across the name server settings.

Most of what I found online were regarding how to setup name servers, which advised something like `ns1.mydomain.com` and then my IP address.

Why should I setup a name server as above (as opposed to what is currently default set by provider)?

Why should I create a second name server like 'ns2', and should it be a different IP or the same as 'ns1'? (If the IP for 'ns1' and 'ns2' match isn't that redundant?)

The cPanel has name servers—do those have to match the domain name servers?

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to run ***your own*** DNS servers? Do you have DNS servers available to you through your registrar or host? I caution you that running your own DNS servers is not for the timid. It requires special considerations and security that makes it expensive. I would seriously recommend against this when other options are available. Or are you confused over the process? We can explain that as well.

Comment: Home »Server Configuration »Basic cPanel & WHM Setup, tat the bottom there is a section called "Nameservers" two are filled, next to them there is an "assign IP address" and "Add an A entry for this nameserver". That is what I am trying to configure.

Comment: I don't think you need to do that. This sounds like a case where you should be talking to your web host. If you have name servers already defined, that my be enough. Give them a call or get on their online chat or send them an e-mail. That will be the best place for your question- honestly. If you do not get a good answer, then we can look again. But I really think your host is the best place to ask.

Comment: They said that I can change it if I want. What I want to know is why would you change it? What is it for? (My questions above)

Comment: If your site is working, I would not change anything. I would not add anything or change the DNS settings until you know how DNS works more and can make informed configuration changes knowing what you are getting into. In this case, it is likely the name servers of your host that you are seeing. There is no need to add more or change them. It is only for your server/site to use when making DNS queries. This is low level stuff that is simply not necessary to change unless you are doing something rather funky like I am as a security analyst. ;-)

Comment: I am trying to learn more. But I cant find any explanation what is the difference between using the hosts name servers or point to my ip. Why would you do something like what this guy does https://youtube.com/watch?v=B4xNNyb5y7o

Comment: You should not have to do this. The setup he appears to be doing is for referencing a DNS server that is installed on his site/server which is something that is completely unnecessary and frankly dangerous from a security stand-point. As well, you can run into issues if it is not set-up right that would have you going around in circles. While this article is a bit technical, it does give you a good understanding of DNS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System I could not find a simpler site that was worth anything or would not add confusion. DNS is a complicated subject really.

Comment: Some domain registrars have a thing called child nameservers.  That is where I set mine up

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you aren't really wanting to set up your own nameservers, rather you are assigning child nameservers.

This may be useful to thinly disguise where your site is hosted e.g. I have done this when I don't want it blatantly obvious that two sites are associated by being with the same hosting company.  Note the 'thinly' :P

Another use is if you are running a hosting business, then you can tell your customers to use ns1.yourhost.com and voila, their domain is managed by your server.  It looks more professional than using your hosting service's nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your own nameservers instructs the domain provider to stop managing the DNS zone file (kinda like setting for a domain)

One of the advantages to this is that it allows easy hosting migration.

In terms of redundancy having two nameserver on one or more IPs that are on the same ip block doesn't matter. Since if one goes down so does the other.
It might help that it is two different network paths. (Don't know)